# json_encode doesnt response correct json data

Tags: php, jquery, header, json

Assume that I have 2 .php files : index.php and ajax.php

This is index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Website title</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    ajax_register = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "act=register",
            success: function(data){
                //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                //alert(json);
                alert(data.result);

            },
            error: function(e){
                alert("Error : " + e);
            }
        });
    };

</script>

<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
    Your name :
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ajax_register()">Register</a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is ajax.php:

```
<?php
$result = array("result"=>"Success");
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

But I always have "Error" alert dialog.

Look in Firebug, I see that the response data contains all html elements instead of only json data.

Try to send header as "json" by edit ajax.php :

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
    $result = array("result"=>"Success");
    echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

But it doesnt work. The response header is always : Content-Type:text/html;

**UPDATE**

This is what ajax.php response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Website title</title>
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        ajax_register = function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: 'ajax.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "act=register",
                success: function(data){
                    //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    //alert(json);
                    alert(data.result);

                },
                error: function(e){
                    alert("Error : " + e);
                }
            });
        };

    </script>

    <form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
        Your name :
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ajax_register()">Register</a>
    </form>
{"result":"Success"}
```

What do I wrong here?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What are the HTML elements in the erroneous response? Is it HTML you recognise (you wrote it), or are they from an error page returned by the webserver? That the error callback is used at all suggests that you are getting something other than a 200 response from the server

Comment: Perhaps the previous response is cached by `$.ajax`. Try to set the `cache` option to `false`. And restart your browser.

Comment: what if you open the ajax.php url directly in browser?

Comment: Must be a server-side issue. I ran the code on my server and it works fine. Check to make sure that ajax.php is being served by the server as a PHP script...

Comment: `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");`

Comment: do you use any apache .htaccess file ?

Comment: It's ok now. I dont know what really happen but it's working fine after restarting system. Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only changed this LOC `<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.js"></script>` to

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

to check your code and its all working fine at my end ..check JS errors may be a case of JS conflicts. (Alerting Success for me). Let me know if problem still persist

`index.php` CODE --

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Website title</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    ajax_register = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "act=register",
            success: function(data){
                //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                //alert(json);
                alert(data.result);

            },
            error: function(e){
                alert("Error : " + e);
            }
        });
    };

</script>

<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
    Your name :
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ajax_register()">Register</a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

`ajax.php` CODE ---

```
<?php
$result = array("result"=>"Success");
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

Alerting `Success` on clicking at register.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's working fine after restarting my system. But I marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: @quangtruong1985 thanks a lot man ... i think it just need a hard refresh ..cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

i think you can change this line

```
 data: "act=register",
```

to

```
 data: " act : register ",
```